# parse nested expressions to retreive each functions in list in python

Tags: python, parsing

Suppose I have a expression as shown below i want to parse this and extract inner expressions in ascending order in list

```
expression = DATENAME('weekday',DATEADD('month',3,[OrderDate]))
```

I want output as

```
["DATEADD('month',3,[OrderDate])","DATENAME('weekday',DATEADD('month',3,[OrderDate]))"]
```

but I am getting output as

```
["'weekday',DATEADD('month',3,[OrderDate])", "DATENAME('weekday',DATEADD('month',3,[OrderDate]))"]
```

This is what I have tried

```
result = []
expression = "DATENAME('weekday',DATEADD('month',3,[OrderDate]))"
for i in range(len(expression)):
    for j in range(len(expression)):
        if expression[i:j+1].count('(') == expression[i:j+1].count(')') != 0:
            if (expression[i-1] == '(' or i == 0) and expression[j] == ')':
                result.append(expression[i:j+1])
result.reverse()
printg(result)
```

For the below expression my code returns correct result

```
CONTAINS((Replace(Lower(UPPER([ProductName]+[ProductName])),'chaichai','chai')),'chai')
['UPPER([ProductName]+[ProductName])', 'Lower(UPPER([ProductName]+[ProductName]))', "Replace(Lower(UPPER([ProductName]+[ProductName])),'chaichai','chai')", "(Replace(Lower(UPPER([ProductName]+[ProductName])),'chaichai','chai'))", "CONTAINS((Replace(Lower(UPPER([ProductName]+[ProductName])),'chaichai','chai')),'chai')"]
```

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

follow code maybe do it

```
s="CONTAINS([Quantity (Products)],'10')"

fangKuoHaoPairsIndex=[]
fangKuoHaoPairsFromIndex=[]
for i in range(len(s)):
    if s[i] == "[":
        fangKuoHaoPairsFromIndex.append(i)
        pass
    elif s[i] == "]":
        fromIdx=fangKuoHaoPairsFromIndex.pop()
        fangKuoHaoPairsIndex.append((fromIdx,i))

for i in range(len(s)):
    if s[i]=="(":
        a.append(i)

    elif s[i]==")":
        fromIdx=a.pop()

        fromIdx2=max(a[-1],s.rfind(",", 0, fromIdx))

        flag=False
        for (fromIndex, toIndex) in fangKuoHaoPairsIndex:
            if fromIdx2 + 1 >= fromIndex and i <= toIndex:
                flag=True
                break
        if flag==False:
            print(s[fromIdx2+1:i+1])
```

Comment: thanks ,but with this expression `CONTAINS([Quantity (Products)],'10')` it returns output as `[Quantity (Products)` and 
`CONTAINS([Quantity (Products)],'10')` .output shhould only be `CONTAINS([Quantity (Products)],'10')`

Comment: why dont you want output  "Quantity (Products)" ?   now i am confused

Comment: Quantity (Products) is not a function.its a parameter within a function

Comment: in expression = DATENAME('weekday',DATEADD('month',3,[OrderDate]))

DATEADD is also a parameter of DATENAME function , but why you want output "DATEADD('month',3,[OrderDate])" ?

if  expression  is CONTAINS( Quantity (Products),'10') , 
should "Quantity (Products)" be outputed ?

Comment: DATEADD its a parameter and also a function name..whereas "Quantity (Products)" is only a parameter(a table name) which is enclosed within []

Comment: if expression is CONTAINS( '10' , Quantity (Products) ) ,
 should "Quantity (Products)" be outputed ?

Comment: no bcz its not a function name just a parameter(a table name enclosed within [])

Comment: ok another question, if exp is UPPER( ProductName1+[ProductName2])  ,
then you want output ProductName1? because it is not enclosed by [] ?

Comment: I will not have this scenario bcz..all tables names will be enclosed by []